# Remove items from array on clicking back <-- button on browser

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

**.ts file**

```
public selectedFolders: string[] = []; // Array to store the selected folders


// Current content for folder1 is being displayed when I click on the folder -- the content for folder2 gets displayed 

public updateDocumentsList(item: Model) {
this.selectedFolders.push(item.name);
this.router.navigate(['../url'], {queryParams:​​​​​​​ { a: this.a, b: this.b, site: this.siteName, sitefolderID: item.id}​​​​​​​​​​​, relativeTo: this.route }​​​​​);
}
```

**.html file**

```html
// Passing the value stored on selectedFolders array here to display Example: Folder1 > Folder2

<a class="Folders-item" 
[href]="" 
target="_blank" 
*ngFor="let selectedFolder of selectedFolders; let i= index" 
(updateDocumentsList)="updateDocumentsList($event)">> {{ selectedFolders }} </a>
```

**Question:**

When clicking the back arrow the content for `folder1` is updated but the display still shows `Folder1 > Folder2`

**Expected Behavior:**

On clicking on back arrow, the folder structure should get updated too and only display `Folder1`

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is because `.push` affects the current array and doesn't change the reference to the array thereby forcing change detection.

Try:

```
public updateDocumentsList(item: Model) {
  this.selectedFolders = [...this.selectedFolders, item.name];
  this.router.navigate(['../url'], {queryParams:​​​​​​​ { a: this.a, b: this.b, site: 
   this.siteName, sitefolderID: item.id}​​​​​​​​​​​, relativeTo: this.route }​​​​​);
}
```

Doing `this.selectedFolders = [....]` assigns `selectedFolders` to a new area in memory and forces change detection.